# Incorrect DebugKeyStorePath

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

The 'Debug Android Key Hash' in the Inspector FaceBookSettings does not work (Windows7) because it uses an incorrect DebugKeyStorePath. This is caused because the drive ("C:\") is not included in the HOMEPATH.

Only `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH")` is used to build the path, which does not contain the drive. For the full path the `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE")` should be added in front of the path.

Until now I manually fix this after each SDK update by modifying FacebookAndroidUtil.cs:

```
private static string DebugKeyStorePath
{
    get
    {
        return (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor) ?
           System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE") + //FIX PATH!!!
           System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH") + 
           @"\.android\debug.keystore" : 
           System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) +
           @"/.android/debug.keystore";
    }
}
```

I have not checked if it is fixed in SDK 5.1 BETA because the link currently downloads FacebookSDK-140101-beta and not FacebookSDK-140401-beta (probably just a wrong filename, but to be sure I skipped that update for now).

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Facebook SDK v6.0